# Pandas group by unique counts as new column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a new column `col` in my pandas data frame which will be calculated as:

```
select count(distinct ITEM) as col
from base_data
where STOCK > 0 
group by DEPT, CLAS, DATE;
```

For which I am doing

```
assort_size = base_data[(base_data['STOCK'] > 0)]\
.groupby(['DEPT','CLAS','DATE'])['ITEM']\
.transform('nunique')
```

Basically for each dept, class, date combination I want to get number of items which are present in stock. So I then want to result of this merge with parent data frame but result is coming out as `pandas.core.series.Series` so I can not `append (axis=1)` it back (row count differs e.g. 1.6 M Vs 1.4 M). Also I don't have `DEPT, CLAS, DATE` columns to join. What can I do here to get dataframe with group by columns?

Is there any better way to create new column directly in parent pandas dataframe (`base_data`)than creating a new object like I am creating `assort_size`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) first, then `groupby` with [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) and last [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
base_data = pd.DataFrame({"DEPT": ["a", "a", "b", "b"],
                   "CLAS":['d','d','d','d'],
                   "STOCK": [-1, 1, 2,2],
                   "DATE":pd.to_datetime(['2001-10-10','2001-10-10',
                                          '2001-10-10','2001-10-10']),
                   "ITEM":[1,2,3,4]})

print (base_data)
  CLAS       DATE DEPT  ITEM  STOCK
0    d 2001-10-10    a     1     -1
1    d 2001-10-10    a     2      1
2    d 2001-10-10    b     3      2
3    d 2001-10-10    b     4      2

assort_size = base_data[(base_data['STOCK'] > 0)]\
.groupby(['DEPT','CLAS','DATE'])['ITEM'].nunique().rename('n_item')
print (assort_size)
DEPT  CLAS  DATE      
a     d     2001-10-10    1
b     d     2001-10-10    2
Name: n_item, dtype: int64

print (base_data.join(assort_size, on=['DEPT','CLAS','DATE']))
  CLAS       DATE DEPT  ITEM  STOCK  n_item
0    d 2001-10-10    a     1     -1       1
1    d 2001-10-10    a     2      1       1
2    d 2001-10-10    b     3      2       2
3    d 2001-10-10    b     4      2       2
```

Comment: I used this along with `assort_size =assort_size.to_frame().reset_index()` to convert `Pandas.series` to `Pandas.dataFrame`. This followed by join is much much faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` instead of `transform` for complex calculations and move the filter inside the apply function, use `assign` to make a new column for each group, this will create a data frame with the newly calculated column, no post assignment is needed:

```
(base_data.groupby(['DEPT','CLAS','DATE'], group_keys=False)
 .apply(lambda g: g.assign(n_item = g.ITEM[g.STOCK > 0].nunique())))
```

*An example*: (find the number of unique values in column C where B > 0 grouped by column A.)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["a", "a", "b", "b"], "B": [-1, 1, 2,2],"C":[1,2,3,4]})

df.groupby('A', group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: g.assign(n_item = g.C[g.B > 0].nunique()))

#   A   B   C   n_item
#0  a  -1   1        1
#1  a   1   2        1
#2  b   2   3        2
#3  b   2   4        2
```

Comment: This works but it is darn slow. For 1.7 M rows data frame it took ~ 10+ mins before I killed the run. in R data.table I used to do `base_data <- base_data[BOH_Q>0 & EOH_Q>0,':='(assort_size = length(unique(ITEM))),by=.(DEPT,CLAS, DATE)]` which used to finish within few seconds.

Comment: If the performance is an issue and there are no duplicated index, you can assign the `assort_size` you calculated back to the original data frame as `base_data['n_item'] = assort_size`, it will align the index for you.